# Creating new memory graph template with cdef and OID for cisco router

Tags: monitoring, snmp, network-monitoring, oid, cacti

I want to create memory graph on cacti. But I have 2 OID for this, used memory (with OID) free memory (with OID).  I want to create a graph which function for CDEF used to be (used_mem /(used_mem +free_mem))*100. I mean I want to see on this graph used memory percent on used+free memory.
How can I do this? I try to create two data source for one data template but I couldn't use OID's.

Comment: Hi,

I solve this problem with using solution above;

http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=8415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with using solution above;

http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=8415